# how to add resource to already existing resource in apigateway using CDK (linked to lambda)?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I created a resource '/v6/users' inside UsersStack file (extends cdk.Stack):

```
const apiPrefix = 'users';

const usersApi = new RestApi(this, 'usersApi', {
    deployOptions: {
        stageName: buildConfig.environment,
    },

    defaultCorsPreflightOptions: {
        allowHeaders: [
            'Content-Type',
            'X-Amz-Date',
            'Authorization',
            'X-Api-Key',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
            'X-Amz-Security-Token',
            'X-Amz-User-Agent',
        ],
        allowMethods: ['OPTIONS', 'GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],
        allowCredentials: false,
        allowOrigins: Cors.ALL_ORIGINS,
    },
});

const usersResourceApi = usersApi.root.addResource('v6', {
    defaultMethodOptions: {
        authorizationType: AuthorizationType.IAM,
    },
});
const userApi = usersResourceApi.addResource(apiPrefix);
```

then I wanted to add another sub resource (v6/users/getAll) but inside another file (extends Construct) and then I imported the file inside UsersStack.

my understanding is that I have to output the resource from UsersStack so I can use it inside the Construct like this :

```
        new cdk.CfnOutput(this, `userResourcesId`, {
        exportName: `usersResourcesId`,
        value: userApi.resourceId,
    });
```

then inside the construct we can use it like this :

```
const api = RestApi.fromRestApiId(this, 'usersApi', cdk.Fn.importValue('userResourcesId'));
```

the problem is I can see the API added in the console  :
[image]
but it's not linked correctly to the lambda, I'm using this code :

```
 const usersResource = api.root.resourceForPath('/');
 const getAll = usersResource.addResource('getAll', {
    defaultMethodOptions: {
        authorizationType: AuthorizationType.IAM,
    },
 });

 const lambdaIntegration = new LambdaIntegration(getAllF, {
    proxy: false,
    passthroughBehavior: PassthroughBehavior.WHEN_NO_TEMPLATES,

    integrationResponses: [{
        statusCode: '200',
        responseParameters: {
            'method.response.header.Content-Type': "'text/html'",
            'method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "'*'",
        },
        responseTemplates: {
            'text/html': "$input.json('$')"
        },
    }, ],
    requestTemplates: {
        'application/json': apiRequestTemplate
    },
 });

 getAll.addMethod('GET', lambdaIntegration, {
    methodResponses: [{
        statusCode: '200',
        responseParameters: {
            'method.response.header.Content-Type': true,
            'method.response.header.Content-Length': false,
            'method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin': true,
        },
    }, ],
 });
```

in lambda console, it's showing this error :

[image]

(some values were edited for the sake of the post)